# Правило использования жи ши

Tags: орфография

Уважаемые знатоки! Подскажите: в слове *ежик* и *шалашик* работает ли правило жи/ши? Или надо поставить под ударение *ежи*, *шалаши* и потом применить жи/ши? Или это правило использования суффикса ИК/ЕК?
И какой ответ должен дать ученик 3 класса в начале учебного года![image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как ударение повлияет на правило "жи/ши"?

Comment: @IvanOlshansky ну если проанализировать ход мысли автора вопроса, то в безударной позиции надо выбирать не между Ы и И, а между И и Е. В словах "овражек" и "ёжик" суффиксы на слух неразличимы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю, что это сложно для много знающих взрослых (это я про ИК-ЕК), а не для ученика начальной школы.

В ответе первого ученика они должны увидеть ошибку: эти орфограммы нельзя проверить ударением в однокоренных словах, потому что И здесь **не в корне, а в суффиксе** ёж-ёжик, шалаш - шалашик. Значит, верен второй вариант - орф. жи-ши.

Намёк в частичном транскрибировании: что писать - Ы или И.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то очень напутано... А как дословно звучит задание?

Строго говоря, здесь нет правила жи/ши. Здесь есть правило на правописание суффиксов ик/ек, известное также как правило "ключик-замочек".

Правило это такое. Надо поставить слово в позицию, где проявляется беглость гласной:   ***нет ежика, шалашика***. Если гласная не является беглой, то суффикс ИК.

Но, боюсь, это правило не в третьем классе проходят. Проверять гласные позицией под ударением в суффиксах вообще говоря нельзя, хотя иногда и проходит, но в целом это правило для проверки гласных в корне.

А что касается жи и ши, то написания "шалашик" и "ёжик" ему не противоречат, то с его помощью вообще нельзя проверять выбор между И и Е, не только в суффиксах ИК и ЕК.

Посмотрел в интернете. Вы знаете, очень может быть, что "ключик и замочек" - это как раз третий класс. Тогда смело формулируйте это правило для обоснования ИК в ежике и шалашике. Жи/Ши, как сказал, как обоснование тут не работает.

Comment: Проблема в том, что суффикс ик/ек не проходили. А задание такое попалось в контрольной. В интернете же пишут, что жи/ши пиши через И если буква стоит под ударением.     С другой стороны разве буква И спорит с Е? Согласно фонетике будет йожык. Зачем применять правило суффиксов?

Comment: *В интернете же пишут, что жи/ши пиши через И если буква стоит под ударением* Не надо читать глупости из интернета.------------- *Согласно фонетике будет йожык* - где такую фонетику проходили? А "камушек" - не хотите "согласно фонетике" написать? -------- Я не знаю, как могло попасться в контрольную подобное задание, если ик/ек "не проходили". Возможно учителка тоже очень многое из интернета узнала о русском языке, все вопросы - к ней.

Comment: Увидел картинку. Н-да.... @Людмила, боюсь, тут без вас не обойдется.